# UserCreationForm doesn't save the password commit=False

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-forms

**I create a registration form on HTML ajax pull the data and send it to UserCreationForm via a function in views.py. But when I check the user I realized the password is not saved.**
I am using ajax so I took the data per field. And in the view function, I had to add the field values one by one. I used set_password but didn't help.

Any help will very appreciated thank you
My Form:

```
class RegisterForm(UserCreationForm):
    username = forms.CharField(max_length=100 , widget=forms.TextInput(
        attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    email = forms.EmailField(max_length=100, widget=forms.EmailInput())
        
    password1 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput(
        attrs={'class': "form-control"}))
    
    email.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['username', 'email', 'password1', 'password2']

    def save(self, commit=True):
        user = super(UserCreationForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user.email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        user.set_password(self.cleaned_data['password1'])
        if commit:
            user.save()
        return user
```

My View:

```
   def home(request):
    register_form = RegisterForm()
    workshop_form = WorkshopCreateForm
    if request.method == 'POST':
        register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        username = request.POST.get('username')
        print(username)
        email = request.POST.get('email')
        password1 = request.POST.get('pass1')
        password2 = request.POST.get('pass2')
        if register_form.is_valid():
            pended_form = register_form.instance
            pended_form.username = username
            pended_form.email = email
            if password1 == password2:
                pended_form.set_password(password1)
                pended_form.save()
                ctx = {
                    'username': pended_form.username,
                    'password': pended_form.password,
                    'created': True,
                    'success': True,
                    'status':'You created your account',
                }
                return JsonResponse(ctx)
            else:
                ctx = {
                    'username': '',
                    'password': '',
                    'created': False,
                    'success': False,
                    'status':'error',
                    'msg': _('Passwords do not match')
                }
                return JsonResponse(ctx)
                #! TODO: Create a function and import login func from there
        else:
            ctx = {
                    'created': False,
                    'success': False,
                    'status':'error',
                    'msg': _('You need to enter a valid username and email')
                }
            return JsonResponse(ctx)
    return render(request, 'web/home.html', {'register_form':register_form})
```

After the user is saved:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to use the RegisterForm() directly without parsing. I don't need to parse the data. I just put the data inside of RegisterForm() so the problem is solved.

```
if request.method == 'POST' and request.POST.get("operation") == "register":
        register_form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
        if register_form.is_valid():
            register_form.save()
            return JsonResponse(ctx)
```

Answer (score 0):

just create a new user.

```
User.create.objects(username, email)
user.set_password(password)
user.save()
```

you can do this in your view